# How to select Autogenerated web element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have this xpath `//*[@id="s2id_autogen8"]`

After Refresh Xpath gets change. Can someone please advise how can I create customized XPath for this.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input select2-default" id="s2id_autogen38" style="width: 220px;">
```

Comment: What do you mean by xpath gets changed? is it the id or any attribute that gets changed?

Comment: Why not select by class name?

Comment: Does id is changing? Can U locate element above input ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if id is changing and if class is not changing and also if you want to go with xpath only

```
//input[contains(@class,'select2-input')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your xpath to -

```
//*[contains(@id,'s2id_autogen')]
```